# I have two websites. I try to iframe from one to another but I get "iframe refused to connect"

Tags: html, iframe, drupal, x-frame-options

I have two websites.

Both websites sit on the same hosting environment.

I have broad control over the hosting environment.

One website is a Drupal website and the other is a static (plain HTML website).

I try to **iframe-embed** one of the HTML webpages of the second, static website into the Drupal website, but I get:

> iframe refused to connect

[image]

When checking the Drupal website from browser console, I get:

> Refused to display 'https://example.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I don't understand this error (shouldn't `sameorigin` be the correct directive to allow embedding?).

What security directive should I change, and where, to allow the iframe to be displayed?

I have already tried to put the following directive in `.htaccess` of the second, static website:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are they [from SAMEORIGIN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)? You describe them as two websites, and should probably explain the relationship. I'm not certain this question is about security, but rather web development.

Comment: These are two different websites (different web domains). I guess I should use "ALLOW ALL".

Answer (score 0):

You should read up about [origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) (they're very important; they are the concept that underlies most web security boundaries). An origin has nothing to do with the physical, logical, or legal source of a web page; the browser does not, and cannot, know any of that. An origin is simply the tuple (ordered fixed-length collection) of **Protocol**, **Hostname**, **Port**. ("Hostname" here typically meaning the fully-qualified domain name, not just any part of it, but local-network sites often just use hostname.) You say you "have two sites", by which I assume you mean they have different domain names. If they have different domain names, they *can't* have the same origin, because all three parts of the tuple must match. Thus, specifying `SAMEORIGIN` on one of them will obviously not allow the other to frame it; they aren't the same origin! As far as anybody's browser knows, the parent page is an unrelated malicious site trying to violate the security constraints of the would-be guest page.

Possible solutions:

- Remove the X-Frame-Options directive from the guest page. This will let *anybody* frame it, though, so make sure that's OK if you do it (if the second page is static and unauthenticated then of course it is; anybody could simply fake the embedding by serving the same static content so XFO is doing nothing for you).
- Replace the X-Frame-Options header (on the guest page) with a [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) header that specifies a [`frame-ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive allowing the parent site.
- Move both pages to the same origin, either by copying the page to the other server/site, or adding a server-side fetch for that path which grabs it from the other server.
- Use CORS to request the embeddable content across origins, and embed the response HTML in the parent page, possibly in an iframe's `srcdoc`. (Included only for completeness; this is almost certainly not the best approach here, as configuring CORS correctly is far harder than the other options.)